# Modifying the TOC title/entries in amsart

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

Is it possible to modify the title of the table of contents using the class amsart?
I could modify the font of the title, but not the title itself.
I'd like to avoid the \scshape and to use capital letters.
The first part was done, but I can't do the second...

Also, is it possible to have sections headings with capital letters and to make them appear in lowercase letters in the TOC?

Thanks to everybody

Comment: The `tocloft` package is what is often used for this but `amsart` doesn't like it much. However, pressing on with `\usepackage{tocloft}` and ignoring the error message it seems to do what you want.

Comment: Regarding section headings, `amsart` allows an optional form to be specified: `\section[...]{...}`.  To get rid of the `\scshape`, simply `\renewcommand{\contentsnamefont}{}`,

Comment: Would you type `\section{Section}` and then it should appear as `SECTION` in the text and `section` in the ToC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two commands for the first question.

As for the second question, it seems that it is the default behavior of `amsart.cls`

[image: xx]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text  

\renewcommand{\contentsnamefont}{\bfseries} %<<<<<  
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{New name for TOC} %<<<<<   

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

1.  \kant[1]    

\section{Section II}

2.  \kant[2]
    
\end{document}
```